# How to import AnalysisException in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, exception, pyspark, try-catch

I can't find how to import `AnalysisException` in PySpark so I can catch it. For example:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 2]], ['A', 'A'])

try:
  df.select('A')
except AnalysisException as e:
  print(e)
```

Error message:

```
NameError: name 'AnalysisException' is not defined
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can import it here:

```
from pyspark.sql.utils import AnalysisException
```

This is shown in the error traceback like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: cannot resolve ...
```

Comment: It's strange that I couldn't find it in docs.

Comment: @MykolaZotko perhaps they didn't expect people to attempt to catch this...

Comment: @MykolaZotko I can't find it in the docs too. I just saw the path of the exception from the exception itself (second code snippet).

Comment: There is a source code though: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/utils.html